# Why does a fresh SQL Server instance with the same details as the original think that my DB backup is in the original location?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, sql-server-2019

So I'm working on a server application for a large government body and need to setup a development environment to test on. For this I'm using a Vagrant-controlled VM with Windows Server 2019 installed as the guest OS and SQL Server 2019 as the DB engine.

After creating and subsequently destroying the VM, then rebuilding it I am now trying to restore a DB backup to a fresh instance with the exact same instance name, logins etc. But I get this error from my PowerShell script:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM DISK = '.\db-name.bak'"

Invoke-SqlCmd : Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.JIRADB\MSSQL\Backup\db-name.bak'. Operating system     
error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM DISK = '.\db-name.bak'"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

What gives?! Clearly the backup file now exists at `C:\Users\vagrant` but SQL Server seems to think that it should be in the original, default backup location.

Obviously, I can simply move the backup file back to the original location, but I'd like to know why SQL Server is expecting that. MTIA! :D

Answer (score 1):

The .\ is not interpreted in the Query parameter as 'current directory' and so SQL looks for the file in its default backup location. You have a couple of options

1. Change the Query value and specify the full path to the file
2. Pass a variable into the Query string (see below)

Option 1 is the simplest, but you may have need of using variables elsewhere, so here's an example:

```
$StrArray = "VAR1='C:\Temp\db-name.bak'"
invoke-sqlcmd -query "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = `$(VAR1)" -Variable $StrArray
```

$StrArray is an array of strings that take the form *Variable Name*='*Variable Value*' and each is substituted in your query string at run time.

[Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten about SQL variables as it's been a while since I used SQL Server, and I'm a PowerShell n00b as you seem to have correctly assumed lol. But I could swear I tried option 1 and got the same result, which is why I posted here. Will test that again when I get a chance and if it indeed works, will accept your answer :-)